# Change woocommerce cart link in menu

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I use Woocommerce with a dropdown cart menu item (the link is mysite.com/cart). I would like to change the url of the menu-cart item to mysite.com/products only here (not the full cart page url). 
Is that possible any way?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain your question in the proper way.

Comment: I have a woocommerce store with the original cart items button in the header menu. If i click on it, the link takes me to the cart page. I would like to change the url of this link to `mysite.com/products` .
However when i hover on this menu item, there is a dropdown menu with the elements of the cart and a "view cart" button (i dont want to modify the button link, only the link in the menu)

Comment: @LoicTheAztec its not duplicated content!
as i sad, i dont want to change the buttons in the widget! i want to modify the **cart link in the menu**

Comment: @walacky Yes it is. The linked answer, will show you the way to do it.